# Is there a short way in networkx(Python) to calculate the reachability matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

Imagine I have given a directed graph and I want a numpy reachability matrix whether a path exists, so R(i,j)=1 if and only if there is a path from i to j;

networkx has the function has_path(G, source, target), however it is only for specific source and taget nodes; Therefore, I've so far been doing this:

```
import networkx as nx
R=np.zeros((d,d))
for i in range(d):
   for j in range(d):
      if nx.has_path(G, i, j):
         R[i,j]=1
```

Is there a nicer way to achieve this?

Here would be a minimum example with real numbers:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

c=np.random.rand(4,4)
G=nx.DiGraph(c)
A=nx.minimum_spanning_arborescence(G)

adj=nx.to_numpy_matrix(A)
```

Here we can see that this would be the adjacency but not reachability matrix - with my number example I would get

```
adj=
matrix([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.47971056, 0.        ],
        [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.16101491, 0.04779295, 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

So there is a path from 4 to 2 (adj(4,2)>0) and from 2 to 3 (adj(2,3)>0) so there also would be a path from 4 to 3 but adj(4,3)=0

Comment: Please add a sample input and expected output

Comment: 1 minute, will do :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [all_pairs_shortest_path_length](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path_length):

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

c = np.random.rand(4, 4)
G = nx.DiGraph(c)
length = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path_length(G))

R = np.array([[length.get(m, {}).get(n, 0) > 0 for m in G.nodes] for n in G.nodes], dtype=np.int32)

print(R)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Comment: This works - thank you very much; I also had this function in mind but thought there might be some easier way that does not need to calculate the shortest path for each pair of nodes

Comment: Isn't it the transpose of reachability matrix described in the question?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to  find all descendants of each node, and set the corresponding rows that are reachable to 1:

```
a = np.zeros((len(A.nodes()),)*2)

for node in A.nodes():
    s = list(nx.descendants(A, node))
    a[s, node] = 1
```

---

```
print(a)

array([[0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works also well; The advantage here is that is it much easier to understand what is going on compared to the other example; But in contrary, it is a bit longer; From computation they are probably comparable

Comment: Longer as in more lines of code? Generally speaking, and specially when it comes to involved tasks as this one, readability is *very* important. So narrowing down to as fewer lines of code as possible at the expense of readability is not advisable. As per the second point not so sure, we'd have to check :) @Johannes